# Leaflet 6 upgrading from version 5.x

Tags: leaflet

This is the result after the upgrade http://jsfiddle.net/tYbcu/1/
Everything seem to be in a small square in the middle.

This is the code before http://jsfiddle.net/cliff/CRRGC/

What's happening here?

Everything I set is almost the same

```
map = L.map("map", {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 7,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 0);
```

Comment: setting 'minZoom' to 1 seems to fix it. Not sure why. A bug in the new release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the maxZoom to 6

```
map = L.map("map", {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 6,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 0);
```